# Get Customer Review with Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, cgi

All i'm trying to get the items reviews from amazon using Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review
I have tried everything in my low knowledge of perl to try to get it to work but I can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

DESCRIPTION
Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review holds customer reviews.

Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review - Customer Review Class

SYNOPSIS

```
use Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review;
my $rev = Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review->new(
             'rating'        => $rating,
             'summary'       => $summary,
             'content'       => $content,
             'asin'          => $asin,
             'customer_id'   => $customer_id,
             'date'          => $date,
             'helpful_votes' => $helpful_votes,
             'total_votes'   => $total_votes,
);
```

Comment: Please provide a complete script, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: From the test script [004Reviews.t](https://metacpan.org/source/BOUMENOT/Net-Amazon-0.62/t/004Reviews.t) it looks like there should be a method `review_set()` that gives access to the review data

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are pointing to a sub-package being part of [Net-Amazon-0.62](https://metacpan.org/source/BOUMENOT/Net-Amazon-0.62/README).

Reading the README, you can find some request example and `Net::Amazon::Attribute::Review` is one of the attributes of the response.

Digging into the source code of the Response serialization, the object Review is parsed from xml here https://metacpan.org/source/BOUMENOT/Net-Amazon-0.62/lib/Net/Amazon/Response.pm#L123-129 .

If you want to debug the content of the response, you can call the method `as_string`.

You can find a full example of fetching reviews inside the library in this file:

https://metacpan.org/source/BOUMENOT/Net-Amazon-0.62/eg/reviews

Comment: @jason-doe I did not copy paste the snippet due to copyright, but the last link points exactly to what you need